# link-only answers

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

So I did some reviews and then got this comment on a post of mine:

> just so you know, link-only answers are frowned upon by SO. [This
>   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3231088#./3231088?&_suid=1382966602518018460374688052794) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3231226#./3231226?&_suid=138296670697609298139275390724) should both have been deleted, and not
>   flagged as "Looks Good", and now we have to flag them for moderator
>   attention instead of letting users clean it up

Seems like it'd be hard to clean up a deleted post? I mean if the post is kept the OP (original poster) can in theory go back and edit it. Or someone else could to bring in the info.

If nothing else, keeping the post - as opposed to deleting it - gives the OP a chance to get notified about any replies they might receive. ie. replies such as "please don't post just links". If you delete the post all together presumably they wouldn't get any notifications. Their post would be deleted, they wouldn't know why and either they might not visit SO (stack overflow) again or they might make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 18):

The auto-generated comments posted by the VLQ queue will result in notifications to the post author *even if the post is deleted*.  This feature was added specifically so that the problem you describe won't exist.

Users can also see and edit their own deleted posts.

It was wrong of you to mark those posts as "looks good".  They don't look good.

Additionally, that a user made that comment was *fantastic*.  He took the time to explain to you that you were abusing the review queues, and even (briefly) explained why.

If you have a problem deleting very low quality content then don't go to the VLQ queue at all.  Its *purpose* is to help find and delete very low quality content.  Going there and marking VLQ content as good content is harmful in a lot of ways.  It keeps the poor content around, it invalidates the VLQ flags, thus discouraging people from continuing to flag content that should be flagged, and encourages users to continue posing low quality content.

Comment: "If you have a problem deleting very low quality content then don't go to the VLQ queue at all" *buuuut I want badgesssss !*

Comment: @HugoDozois /facepalm

Comment: @HugoDozois Badges? We don't need no stinkin' badges!

Comment: [Badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges, badges. Mushroom! Mushroom!](http://badgerbadgerbadger.com/)

Comment: @Laf admit it, Narwhals [are much cooler](http://www.weebls-stuff.com/songs/Narwhals/)! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The firewall at my job disagrees :( It doesn't like narwhals apparently :\

Comment: I don't have a problem deleting low quality posts. Problem is it's a bit subjective what constitutes a low quality post and it's not like there are any discussions linked to anywhere that I know of on SO that discusses it. Just because a post doesn't look like it's going to get +10 votes doesn't mean it's a bad post. If people are so upset by posts that they link of as being low quality being approved then maybe SO should have some sort of quiz or something. But whatever.

Comment: @neubert Well, for starters, you have all of the reasons to choose from when choosing to delete a post.  You can read through them to see what type of posts that queue is designed to find and handle.  These posts match the link only answer reason.  If you don't know what types of posts should be deleted then *ask*, rather than assuming that everything is a great post.  And of course there *are* discussions on the subject throughout meta for you to read up on. Also, there *are* actually quizes; there are audit reviews which, if you take the wrong action enough times will ban you from the queue.

Comment: @Servy - I've only seen the quizzes for Suggested Edits - not for Low Quality Posts. Or if I have seen them for Low Quality Posts maybe I failed them and it didn't tell me that it was a quiz idk. Also, Low Quality Posts doesn't have too many options. Just Looks Good or Recommend Deletion and Recommend Deletion says nothing about notifying people about why it was deleted. And as for discussions...  well it's like the Add Comment button beside this post right now. I'm just assuming that clicking it will actually add this comment. I'm not looking up a discussion of it. Assuming things is natural.

Comment: @neubert So you've yet to even press "recommend deletion" once?  You haven't seen that when pressing it it brings up a list of reasons to delete the post and that it puts the text of that reason as a comment to the post or upvotes an existing comment with that text?

Comment: @Servy - also, I have recommended deletion before so you're supposition that I'm "assuming that everything is a great post" is not true. eg. http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2837008 And note how that was over a month ago, well before this post.

Comment: @Servy - I have hit it, as my last comment established. I don't click on it enough to have it's behavior memorized. That's like saying "going off memory alone in what order do things appear in the Windows 7 start menu?" idk and it's dumb to assume that someone would.

Comment: More Recommend Deletions that I've done: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3084024 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3127720 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3137235 , etc. Maybe I should create a pastebin with links to everyone I've done? And btw all of these were done before this post.

Comment: @Servy - Well great. I just clicked on "Recommend Deletion" for a random post and got a "This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass." message. I did not *actually* want to recommend deletion. I *wanted* to see this alleged list of options you said I'd be presented with and figured I'd cancel out of it before *actually* recommending deletion. So, near as I can tell, there is no such list. Thanks for getting me closer to having me banned from the queue. But then maybe that was the point, wasn't it? Ugh.

Comment: @neubert The audits assume that when you suggest deletion you've made your decision; on non-audit posts you will see a list of reasons to reject.

Comment: @Servy. That's good to know. And FWIW I do appreciate your patience in explaining things to me. You're the only one that has, in this question, and I appreciate it.