# not constructive flags on meta stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, comments, meta, not-constructive

I suppose this question could be seen as a duplicate of [When should comments be flagged as "not constructive"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186308/186308) but my question is specific to particular comments and I don't think I'd get an answer if I posted my question as an answer to [When should comments be flagged as "not constructive"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186308/186308) . Hence my making this post.

Anyway, the comments in reference are in response to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203301/186308 . They include, among other things, someone saying something like "@HugoDozois /facepalm". I flagged it as not constructive but no action seems to have been taken and I'd like someone to walk me through how exactly it - and some of the other comments there - *are* constructive.

Comment: If all harmless comments not being really constructive are to be removed then moderators would not have time for the real problems. If enough users flag a comment it will be removed automatically.

Comment: It's meta. Even programmers need a place to relax. ♫

Comment: Hey, come on. It's Meta.

Comment: Meta is practically a moderator's (evil) lair.  If all these "not constructive" comments were unwelcome, then they would be deleted quickly.  This would be different on the main site, though.

Comment: The comment hardly qualifies. It is in response to the [*buuuut I want badgesssss* joke](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203300/link-only-answers/203301#comment647787_203301). I'd certainly dispute that flag, use it only where the comment is directed to put someone down, is condescending, etc.

Comment: The only problem with that comment is the lack of Unicorns.

Comment: Just consider humour to be constructive (sometimes / mostly), then all humorous comments and posts are no longer automatically 'not constructive'.

Comment: @Bart unicorns? Why not Zoidberg? (\/)(;,,;)(\/)

Comment: Considering I have had NC flags on "+1 I agree" comments declined on MSO, I don't really buy the "would not have enough time" position @juergend. They obviously have time to review comment flags on meta but just choose to review them differently than on other SE sites.

Comment: I /facepalm at your /facepalm flag. What a waste of time.