# When will I be able to ask questions in Stack Overflow again

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, post-ban

My account on Stack Overflow is currently question banned. What should I do in order to be able to ask questions on Stack Overflow again?

I'm beginner on Stack Overflow and Meta. Please advice me on what I should do.

In the last few minutes I asked some java question on Meta because I can't ask question on Stack Overflow. So I asked in Meta but I didn't receive any answer and my question was vote-down but I don't know why!

Comment: Programming questions are off topic on meta and will never be answered here

Comment: Re the ban, you need to improve your existing content by editing it; get upvotes, and the ban will be automatically lifted. There is no time out for the ban. I note that you have the Peer pressure badge. If possible improve your content rather than deleting it (unless its completely off topic)

Comment: Note that asking somewhere else won't improve your chances of getting out of your ban and actually is worse - there's a reason we have separate sites.

Comment: What's with the bolding of words that do not need bolding? Don't add unnecessary formatting.

Comment: Please note that all of your answers were essentially [link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203300/link-only-answers) - these are not good answers for [so] and have now been deleted. When giving answers, give a full answer in the answer body - by all means, link to additional information, but a person shouldn't have to click away in order to get an answer to their question.

Comment: well, ignoring the rules and the q-ban page definitely isn't going to help.

Answer (score 6):

The question you asked on Meta is a programming question - that's why it got downvoted and put on hold.

Programming questions belong on Stack Overflow, not Meta. Don't try to circumvent a question ban by asking the question on a different site where it is not on-topic.

In regards to your question ban - read [the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) in the ban message and follow the advice in it. That's the **only** way for you to get the ban reversed.

Comment: The OP only has 2 visible questions on SO, which implies there are deleted questions... do they have the potential to be rescued?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards The peer pressure badge suggests they are self deletes however, so they may be able to undelete is they aren't wildly off topic

Comment: @ben "Now I need to use servlet technology in my program but I don't know about servlet.So, please share links or test programs or tutorials" is it.

Comment: Ah, so that's a no then... looks like mod help won't help them. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## Posting programming questions on meta

Programming questions are off topic on meta and will never be answered here.

## Escaping the ban

You need to improve your existing content by editing it; get upvotes, and the ban will be automatically lifted. There is no time out for the ban. In the hope of helping you to edit your existing content into shape I will review your two undeleted questions

#### [whats-wrong-or-missing-in-struts-2-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355010/whats-wrong-or-missing-in-struts-2-jquery-tag)

In this question you post some code and an error, however it is left to the reader to divine what the code is supposed to do, in all questions you should have what you are trying to do, what you did and what went wrong. Here you only have the last 2. Correct this question by editing in a short section on what the code is supposed to achieve.

#### [how-to-cut-and-replace-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784343/how-to-cut-and-replace-string)

Here you do not show what you attempted, this is harder to correct after the fact, but stack overflow questions that do not show an attempt to solve the problem yourself will often be downvoted and closed.

#### Self deleted questions

Sometimes deleting a question is the only possible way forward when a question is completely off topic. However, it makes the ban worse. I note that you have deleted some of your posts (I can see you have a peer pressure badge) but I cannot see the questions themselves. If possible edit them to improve them rather than leaving them deleted. (However Oden♦ suggests your deleted question is a request for links to tutorials. It is unlikely such a question could be edited to be on topic)

## The way forward

Your question *whats-wrong-or-missing-in-struts-2-jquery* seems the likely candidate for improvement, I encourage you to edit it to include the missing information that I have outlined

More general information on the question ban can be found here; [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)